# How should I set up a Social Share bar

Tags: html

So far I have this:

```
<h2>share</h2>
        <ul class="sharing-cl" id="text"> 
        <li><a class="sh-mail" href="">email</a></li> 
        <li><a class="sh-feed" href="">feed</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">twitter</a></li>
        <li><a class="sh-face" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?src=bm&u=http%3A%2F%2Freddurrant.com">facebook</a></li> 
        <li><a class="sh-su" href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http%3A%2F%2Freddurrant.com">stumbleupon</a></li> 
        <li><a class="sh-digg" href="http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Freddurrant.com&title=RED%20Photography&bodytext=A%20Photogaphy%20portfolio%20for%20Ryand%20Durrant">digg</a></li> 
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.reddurrant.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
    </ul>
```

Firstly, How should I fill in the rest of the links?

Secondly, when using the Facebook Button I would like to set the thumbnail to be what I specify, namely the one held at assets/img/thumbnail.png
So I tried using this, which is what you are told to do for the like button:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<meta property="og:title" content="RED Photography: Ryan Durrant - Home"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.reddurrant.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="assets/img/thumbnail.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="RED Photography"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="photography portfolio for Ryan Durrant"/>
```

But no luck.

Any help would be great, especially if you could help me make the rest of them work. To see it in action visit the site at [http://www.reddurrant.com/index.htm](http://reddurrant.com)

Cheers

Comment: For the second try pointing to the url: http://reddurrant.com/assets/img/thumbnail.png

Answer (score 0):

For email try `<li><a class="sh-mail" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com">email</a></li>`

For your rss feed try  `<li><a class="sh-feed" href="http://linktoyourrss.rss">feed</a></li>`

Comment: Would mailto not just send the email to me, while I want it to send to an adress of the users choosing?